# How to know if any value between two values is in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to know with a simple "TRUE" or "FALSE" if, once I define a specific range, a value is in certain column.
So, if I like to know if in the following column there is any value between 3 and 7, I should get a TRUE because of the 5:

```
1
5
8
10
```

So far, the closest option I've tried was the AND function: `=AND(A:A>=3;A:A<=7)`

I could make this option work only with single cells but no with a whole column.

This is a mid step of a larger string, but I'm really stuck on this one. Also, I would like to avoid VBA or any macro related solution if possible.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS()` to count the number that fulfills all criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">3",A:A,"<7")
```

This will return 1 as one cell fulfill both criteria ">3" and "<7".  If you want only a TRUE or FALSE you can change the formula to

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">3",A:A,"<7")>0
```

Additional information about `COUNTIFS()`:

`COUNTIFS()` is a variation of `COUNTIF()` (i.e. Count If), which counts the number of cells that match certain criteria, such as equal to something, larger than something, or is true etc.  While you can only specify one condition for `COUNTIF()`, `COUNTIFS()` let you specify multiple criteria.

More explanation on the usage of the two functions:

`COUNTIFS()` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

`COUNTIF()` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: I didn't know about 'COUNTIFS' (also, the expression in my languaje looked pretty obscure to me). It works perfectly, and once you know how 'COUNTIFS' works, is very easy for me to understand what the formula is doing, so I can make modifications (or corrections) in the future. Thaks a lot.
I'll use your second option though because it will be embedded inside an 'IF'.

Comment: @Ikailhaz Updated my question with additional information on COUNTIFS.

Comment: Thank you for the sources. After reading your answer, I looked for their Spanish counterparts. COUNTIF was easy (CONTAR.SI), but COUNTIFS not so much since it is CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO. I read both of them and I think I know how it works now a bit better. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to count all the elements 
that are outside of the range
and compare that number with the total:

```
=COUNT(A:A)>SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,{"<3",">7"}))
```

Comment: It seems to be a rather simple formula, but it took me a while to understand it. It's very clever! Thank you!
What I figured out was that if the count of the first part (before `>`) is greater than the second part, it would show TRUE, so, why add the SUM function?

Comment: @Ikailhaz: the logic is simple: any element 
is either in the range, or less than the left boundary,
or greater than the right boundary.
`COUNTIF` returns an array of two elements;
the `SUM` of the two is the number of elements 
outside the range. 
When it is less than the total, 
there must be element(s) that fit in the range.

Comment: Now I see! So basically you are asking if the `SUM` of all cells which fulfill the criteria is the same as the total number of cells, right?
Also, didn't know that use of `{ }`. I have to read more about it now that I know of its existence :)